# how to remove Individual declarations in merged declaration must be all exported or all local.ts error?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, redux, angular12

I am implementing a redux store and I am pretty sure this is not a redux issue, in my store file, dog.store.ts I am exporting the store initial state:

```
export interface IDogState{
    dog:number;
}

export const INITIAL_DOG_STATE:IDogState = {
    dog:0
}
```

to later import it in my store.ts file:

```
import { IDogState,dogReducer,INITIAL_DOG_STATE } from "./redux/stores/dog.store";
```

this is where  I get the error:

> Individual declarations in merged declaration 'INITIAL_DOG_STATE' must
> be all exported or all local.ts(2395)
> Binding element 'INITIAL_DOG_STATE' implicitly has an 'any' type.

this was not an issue not long ago, I wonder if it is because a change in typescript or Angular compiler configuration.

Comment: Don't ask "how do I remove the error?" ask "what problem is the error describing and how do I fix that problem?". Errors aren't the problem, they're the symptom.